# Как можно устранить дублирование js кода?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Как можно избавиться от дублирования кода в функции? (блоки if - это явное дублирование)

```js
function sortStrings(arr, param = 'asc') {
  const arrCopy = [...arr];

  if (param === 'asc') {
    arrCopy.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, ['ru', 'eng'], { caseFirst: 'upper' }));
  }

  if (param === 'desc') {
    arrCopy.sort((a, b) => -a.localeCompare(b, ['ru', 'eng'], { caseFirst: 'lower' }));
  }

  return arrCopy;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let caseFirst = param === 'asc' ? 'upper' : 'lower';
let sortFactor =  param === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
arrCopy.sort((a, b) => sortFactor * a.localeCompare(b, ['ru', 'eng'], { caseFirst: caseFirst }));
```

Comment: Можно два раза не спрашивать одно и тоже: `let [caseFisrt, sortFactor] = param === 'asc' ? ['upper', 1] : ['lower', -1]` :)